# Android 2.2 SDK - Unsafe JavaScript attempt to access frame with URL - Google Checkout

Tags: javascript, android, android-emulator, android-webview, google-checkout

I have Google Checkout javascript code inside of an `HTML` file hosted on a server. I can view the cart inside of the Android Emulator Browser, but when I point a WebView `Activity` to the URL, the error I get is `Unsafe JavaScript attempt to access frame with URL` and a blank page displays.

How come this doesn't work in the app but on the same browser the phone uses?

Answer (score 1):

Try to use

```
//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs
```

instead of

```
http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs
```

Omitting the protocol (http or https) will allow the browser to request the file based on the current page protocol